# How do I update programmatically some display_options of my view?

Tags: views, 8

In a custom module (sel), I have a View displaying a custom content entity (Exchange):
[image]
Here is the corresponding configuration file (`views.view.sel_echanges.yml`):

```
id: sel_echanges
label: SÉL-Échanges
module: views
description: ''
tag: ''
base_table: exchange
base_field: id
core: 8.x
display:
  default:
    some code...
  page_1:
    some code...
  page_2:
    display_plugin: page
    id: page_2
    display_title: 'My exchanges'
    position: 1
    display_options:
      display_extenders: {  }
      path: sel/exchanges/myexchanges
      menu:
        type: tab
        title: 'Mes échanges'
        description: ''
        expanded: false
        parent: ''
        weight: 0
        context: '0'
        menu_name: main
      tab_options:
        type: none
        title: ''
        description: ''
        weight: 0
      display_description: ''
      fields:
etc.
```

I'd like to change the menu title ('Mes échanges' by default) in `sel_views_post_execute`:

```
function sel_views_post_execute(ViewExecutable $view)
{
  switch ($view->id()) {
    case 'sel_selistes':
      if ($view->current_display == 'page_1') {
some stuff...
      }
      break;

    case 'sel_echanges':
      if ($view->current_display == 'page_2') {
Code to be done...
      }
      break;
    default:

  }
}
```

I was looking at `$view->setHandlerOption` but I couldn't find how to write the code :-(
Any help?

Comment: The menu links of a View are discovered when a Views configuration is saved, not on run-time.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand your comment. Do you mean that what I want is not  feasible in `sel_views_post_execute`? Would it be possible,in another hook_views?

Comment: Probably not, the menu links provided by Views are static and change only when the configuration saved. On run-time the View is no longer involved.

Comment: OK. Got it! I will abandon the idea. Thanks!